# Difference between using TSLINT vs Sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube, lint, tslint

For many years i have used the available linting files provided in the angular projects created through CLI. Mainly TSLINT rules to lint the project.

I have also learnt that even SONARQUBE checks for code quality through a remote server.

But can someone explain what exactly is the main functional difference between USING A LINT FILE vs using SONARQUBE ?

Which system is best to use ?

Or is it we can use both of them together ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some differences have been highlighted [here](https://stackshare.io/stackups/sonarqube-vs-tslint).

> > What is SonarQube? 
> >
> > SonarQube provides an overview of the overall health of your source code and even more importantly, it highlights issues found on new code. With a Quality Gate set on your project, you will simply fix the Leak and start mechanically improving.
> > What is TSLint? 
> >
> > An extensible static analysis tool that checks TypeScript code for readability, maintainability, and functionality errors. It is widely supported across modern editors & build systems and can be customized with your own lint rules, configurations, and formatters.

Both tools can be classified as static code analysis tool, aiming to find potential problems in your code. TSLint is more customisable w.r.t. coding rules, and SonarQube does *more than static code analysis*  because it also provides feedback on security/vulnerabilities issues.